# My SQL indexing on int field doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, rds

I have a table with index on a int column.

```
Create table sample(
col1 varchar,
col2 int)

Create index idx1 on sample(col2);
```

When I explain the following query

```
Select * from sample where col2>2;
```

It does a full table scan.

Why doesn't the indexing work here?

How can i optimize such queries when table has around 20 million records?

Comment: If the range f values in col2 is e.g. mostly positive, then the restriction (> 2) will include most of the table and thus it will be faster to just go straight to a table scan, which will minimise the disc access. Otherwise it will have to read in the index pages from disc, and then for each entry selected go back to the disc to get the actual row from the table.

Comment: The cardinality of the data stored plays a role in how indexes will function. In your example, is `col2` a unique field? (a primary key?) Can the values be null?

Comment: My real use case is date is stored as int..for eg. 20191210 for Dec 10th. I want to fetch records for last 5 days. So my query will be ' where date > 20191205'

Comment: @anuchadal that's a design bug. Dates are dates, not numbers, not integers, not strings. Use the *correct* type for the job - `date`. The server may still decide a scan is faster, eg if you have too little past data, or if the *actual* query prevents it from using the index

Comment: @anuchadal BTW using an integer like this for date arithmetic is impossible. What is the result of `20191203` - 5 days? Another possible problem is that applying any functions on the column, you prevent the server from using any indexes that cover it. Database server have specific date-related optimizations too, which are lost if you use unrelated types like strings or integers

Comment: Another reason the server decides to do a scan is the use of an unfortunate PK type like a GUID. This means that rows for the last 5 days are spread throughout the table, so the server will have to load *all* data pages anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Just because you create an index, does not mean MySQL will always use it. According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html), here are several reasons why it may choose to use a full table scan over the index:

- The table is so small that it is faster to perform a table scan than to bother with a key lookup. This is common for tables with fewer than 10 rows and a short row length.
- There are no usable restrictions in the ON or WHERE clause for indexed columns.
- You are comparing indexed columns with constant values and MySQL has calculated (based on the index tree) that the constants cover too large a part of the table and that a table scan would be faster. See Section 8.2.1.1, “WHERE Clause Optimization”.
- You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key value) through another column. In this case, MySQL assumes that by using the key it probably will do many key lookups and that a table scan would be faster.

You can use `FORCE INDEX` to ensure your query uses the index instead of allowing the optimizer to determine the appropriate path, although usually MySQL will take the most efficient approach.

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2 FORCE INDEX (index_for_column) WHERE t1.col_name=t2.col_name;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html

Comment: "Just because you create an index, does not mean MySQL will always use it" -- Yup, that pretty much sums it. +1